# Vue3 with Vite only accepts kebab case tags while Vue3 cli accepts Pascal case tags for custom components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

I have a project using Vue3 with Vite (on Laravel) which have a Wiki.vue page which loads a "MyContent.vue" component.

```html
//On MyContent.vue:
<template>
    <div>content component</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "MyContent",
};
</script>
```

```html
//On Wiki.vue:
<template>
    <MyContent />
</template>

<script>
import MyContent from "./wiki/components/MyContent.vue";
export default {
    components: { MyContent },
};
</script>
```

```js
//On vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue({
            template: {
                compilerOptions: {
                    isCustomElement: (tag) => ["MyContent"].includes(tag),
                },
            },
        }),
        laravel(["resources/css/app.css", "resources/js/app.js"]),
    ],
});
```

On Wiki.vue If I dont change the tag from MyContent to my-content the component won't load at all.
I tried to start a new Vue3 Cli project and I notice that the HelloWorld tag is able to remain Pascal case and load properly which I really wonder what makes the difference.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You've configured a compiler option to treat any elements whose name matches `"MyContent"` as custom elements, which prevents them from being parsed as Vue components:

```js
// vite.config.js
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue({
            template: {
                compilerOptions: {                
                    isCustomElement: (tag) => ["MyContent"].includes(tag),
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

`Wiki.vue`'s template tries to use a Vue component named `"MyContent"`, which is ignored per the config above. `HelloWorld.vue` is unaffected by this because the config above only looks for `"MyContent"`.

#### Solution

You should either remove the `isCustomElement` config, or rename `MyContent.vue`. It doesn't sound like you're actually using custom elements, so I think the former is the best solution.